# UINavigationController child view not adjusting size when parent container view constraint changed programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I'm experiencing a very frustrating issue where I am programmatically adjusting the height of a container view in my root view controller via an autolayout constraint, but one of the views down its hierarchy is not updating its size properly and I can't figure out what is broken. When I rotate the device or perform a navigation, everything lays itself out properly again, so it appears there may be a bug in the autolayout code or something.

The hierarchy is somewhat complicated but here's how it works:

Root View Controller -> Container View -> Navigation Controller -> Menu View Controller

It is the MenuViewController that is not updating its size properly. The container view and navigation controller both have the correct height after adjusting the constraint. I can't figure out why the navigation controller is not passing on the layout change to its child until some other event (rotate/navigate) occurs that forces it to recompute its layout.

I've tried everything I can think of to force the view(s) to update their layout (including `setNeedsUpdateConstraints`, `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded`) but nothing I try seems to have any effect!

Answer (score 2):

Well I *finally* managed to get it working by manually adjusting the menu view controller's height in `viewDidAppear`. However this is clearly ugly so if anyone can figure out how to get autolayout to do its job please post and I will reward the answer.

**Update:** I improved my implementation by attaching a delegate to the `UINavigationController` and monitoring its `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:` method and simply doing this:

```
viewController.view.height = navigationController.view.height;
```

That solves the issue for all screens, not just my menu controller. Very strange that this isn't just normal behavior but I guess it computes the height beforehand (before my constraint has been applied) so it can animate into place.